# LVM thinpool shrink

Tags: resize, shrink, lvm

I want to shrink a thinpool but don't manage to do it.
Have some a procedure for that ?

Here is some information:

```
hyper $ sudo lvs
  LV       VG  Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  mailer   lxc Vwi-aotz--  64,00m pool        32,81
  nginx    lxc Vwi-aotz-- 512,00m pool        26,66
  pool     lxc twi-aotz-- 180,00g             2,29   11,45
  vpn      lxc Vwi-aotz--  64,00m pool        33,40
  [...]

hyper dev $ sudo vgs
  VG  #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  lxc   1  15   0 wz--n- 180,00g    0

hyper $ sudo lvreduce -L100G /dev/lxc/pool
  Thin pool volumes lxc/pool_tdata cannot be reduced in size yet.
```

Is it possible to reduce the size of a thinpool ?
If needed, I can copy all the data elsewhere and then restore it, but how to do it properly ?

Comment: There is a lengthy discussion at https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/resizing-pve-data.30506/ without solution